# Phabricator - How to add "Repository Field" from Diffusion to "Create New Project" form

Tags: phabricator

I'd like to add "Repository Field" from Diffusion to "Create New Project" form. So user can add the Repository linked with that project when he creates the project.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you host your own Phabricator or are you using their hosted?  I believe this would have to be done through writing your own extension as described here: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/#advanced-custom-fields . I don't know how this works with hosted, but it's isn't too hard when you host it yourself.

Comment: I host my own one. And writing the extension is out of my knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, it really isn't a simple task.  https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/ tries to help guide you through it. The only other suggestion I would have would be to create a task (Feature Request) using their form: https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/task/edit/form/2/